# correct apply of pandas.apply with lambda

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i would like the column 'extrema' of my DataFrame beeing 'max2015' if 'max215' is bigger than 'max' or smaller than min2015 if 'min2015' is smaller than 'min'

i think it's the most elegant way to solve this with an df.apply - lambda combination but i can't get a correct solution with this.

Code:

```
x['extrema'] = x.apply(lambda df: df['max2015'] if df['max2015'] > df['max']
                  else df['min'] if df['min2015'] > df['min']
                  else np.nan,
                  axis=1)
```

I get the following result, what is not the correct solution.

[image: Result looks like this]

What's my mistake or another good solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Data in the form of text please

Comment: You do not need apply here .

Comment: Why shouldn't I need apply? I think its necessary to iterate trough the data frame

Comment: What wen meant may be is you can use the power of vectorization without using apply.

Comment: @laurenz did you run my code? Any problem with the one I posted and never post the data in the form of image how you think we try our solutions on data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `np.select` i.e

```
Import numpy as np  
df = x.copy()
df['extrema'] = np.select([df['max2015']>df['max'],df['min2015']>df['min']],[df['max2015'],df['min2015']],np.nan)
```

Comment: np.select really sounds like what I am looking for. Thanks for the idea! I just get several error messages with your code. Do I need to convert my panda DF to a np array?

Comment: That was a typo, I'm in my mobile try the updated code.